# Got error to convert RTP files by using ffmpeg tool

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp

I saved RTP packets to a file and tried to convert the RTP file to wav by using ffmpeg tool. Unfortunately, got error from ffmpeg.

Here three types of the RTP file that I saved:

1. save all (RTP header + payload) to a file
2. save the first RTP header and all payload to a file.
3. save all payload without RTP header.

sharing the files below link -->
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aCznHT_3Wp45Ndm50dUb_G_0hyje0O49/view?usp=share_link

"ffmpeg.exe -loglevel debug -f rtp -i input.sdp -i AudioRx_RTP_Packets.rtp out1.wav" ==> got error

"ffmpeg.exe -loglevel debug -f rtp -i input.sdp -i AudioRx_RTP_Header.rtp out2.wav" ==> got error

"ffmpeg.exe -f mulaw -ar 8000 -ac 1 -i AudioRx_Raw_Data.raw -codec:a pcm_mulaw out3.wav" ==> OK

The return error was "Unsupported RTP version packet received". Is there someone experience about converting RTP file ?
Thanks.